# GetTickCount() on WinCE / Compact7 [Hardware-related]

Tags: timer, hardware, windows-ce

According to MSDN the resolution of **GetTickCount()** on Windows is normally 10-16 ms.
And for embedded systems [WinCE] MSDN says:

*"The resolution of the system timer is based on the OEM's setting. Check with the OEM for details."*

In my case I do not have access to such information (I even do not have access to the hardware yet). So what resolution can I usually expect on a modern DIMM-PC ?

THX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For WindowsCE, `GetTickCount` has a resolution of 1ms (at least it was on every machine I've used in the past decade).  Some devices have a higher resolution counter that can be queried using `QueryPerformanceCounter` and the frequency of it is reported by `QueryPerformcanceFrequency`.  This resolution is BSP dependent, not specifically hardware dependent, meaning that even if the hardware has a high frequency clock, it's up to the BSP to read it and report it back.